# Cis-trans isomerism with electron pairs

Tags: nomenclature

Is it possible to name compounds with lone pairs on the double bonded species using the cis-trans nomenclature? For instance, can't you name $\ce{Ph-N=N-Ph}$ by the relative position of the nitrogen atoms' electron pairs?

Comment: Phenyl groups are cis or trans and that's it.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88240

Comment: yes it is. See the [Azobenzene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azobenzene) wikipedia page for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Azobenzene displays [*cis*-*trans* isomerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azobenzene#Trans-cis_isomerization). The two isomers can be interconverted using UV/Visible-irradiation. The less stable *cis*-isomer will relax back to the more stable *trans*-isomer, but the lifetime of the *cis*-isomer is long enough to allow observation and characterization.

Comment: is the fact that electron pairs and alkyl groups are the high-priority groups only because they're just...defined that way? Also, since you can't really use CIP to classify isomers with electron pairs, can you drop a link to a resource specifying the relative priorities of electron pairs and other such groups, if there's any list of that sort?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, most of linear imines and exocyclic imines display $E/Z$-isomerism (commonly known as $cis/trans$-isomerism) with a lone pair on the nitrogen, which is a part of the double bond. The isomerism follows various mechanisms. For instances, $cis/trans$-isomerism of azobenzene a noted elsewhere is operated by UV/vis-irradiation is a good example. The mechanism of this transformation has been depicted as follows (Ref.1):

[image: Mechanism of isomerism of azobenzene]

Similar to *cis/trans*-isomerism in alkenes, extensive studies has been done on azo-compounds and imines. For example, acid-catalyzed $E/Z$-isomerization of imines has been reported frequently (Ref.2,3). The abstract of Ref.2 states that:

> The kinetics and mechanism of acid-catalyzed *Z/E* isomerization of *O*-methylbenzohydroximoyl chloride (**1Za** and **1Ea**), methyl *O*-methylbenzohydroximate (**1Zb** and **1Eb**), ethyl *O*-methylbenzohydroximate (**1Zc** and **1Ec** and five para and meta substituted derivatives), *O*-methylcinnamohydroximoyl chloride (**2Za** and **2Ea**), and methyl *O*-methylcinnamohydroximate (*2Zb* and *2Zb*) have been investigated. The kinetics of *Z/E* isomerization of these imines have been studied in glacial acetic acid (**1Ea** and **1Zc**) and in dioxane solutions containing $\ce{HCl}$, trifluoromethanesulfonic acid, or tetrafluoroboric acid (**1Ea**, **1Zb**, **2Ea**, and **2Zb**). The isomerization takes place by either (a) rotation about the carbon−nitrogen double bond of the protonated imine (iminium ion rotation) or (b) nucleophilic attack on the protonated imine to form a tetrahedral intermediate that undergoes stereomutation and loss of the nucleophile (nucleophilic catalysis). The hydroximoyl chlorides **1Ea** and **2Ea** only isomerize by the nucleophilic catalysis mechanism. The hydroximate **1Zb** appears to be capable of isomerizing by either mechanism. The hydroximate **2Zb** may be isomerizing only by iminium ion rotation. Theoretical calculations support the notion that increased conjugation in the protonated imine increases the rate of iminium ion rotation.

[image: cis-trans isomerism of imines]

Photochromic properties of a series of novel pyrrolidene imines bearing functionalized aryl or naphthyl moieties was studied by UV spectroscopy (Ref.4):

[image: cis-trans isomerism of pyrrolidene imines]

> UV irradiation of these heterocyclic Schiff bases at room temperature promotes the *trans–cis* photoisomerization of the $\ce{C=N}$ double bond with formation of a variable amount of the *cis*-isomer that, in the absence of light, returns thermally to the original form in few seconds. The thermal *cis–trans* re-isomerization of these molecular switches is much more slower than for the common benzylidene aniline-type imines, allowing the observation of the photochromic phenomena at room temperature.

Another interesting studies have been done with indigo derivatives (Ref.5) noting that:

> Substituted indigo derivatives undergo photoisomerization of the central double bond if both nitrogen atoms are functionalized. Indigo itself however does not photoisomerize because of a competing and highly efficient excited‐state proton transfer...

[image: isomerism of substituted indigo dyes]

---

**References:**

1. H. M. Dhammika Bandara, Shawn C. Burdette, "Photoisomerization in different classes of azobenzene," *Chem. Soc. Rev.* **2012**, *41(5)*, 1809-1825 (https://doi.org/10.1039/C1CS15179G).
2. James E. Johnson, Nora M. Morales, Andrea M. Gorczyca, Debra D. Dolliver, Michael A. McAllister, "Mechanisms of Acid-Catalyzed *Z/E* Isomerization of Imines," *J. Org. Chem.* **2001**, *66(24)*, 7979–7985 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jo010067k).
3. James E. Johnson, Nancy M. Silk, Elizabeth Ann Nalley, Mohammed Arfan, "Mechanism of an acid-catalyzed geometric isomerization about a carbon-nitrogen double bond," *J. Org. Chem.* **1981**, *46(3)*, 546–552 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00316a013).
4. Paulo J. Coelho, M. Cidália R. Castro, M. Manuela M. Raposo, "Reversible *trans–cis* photoisomerization of new pyrrolidene heterocyclic imines," *Journal of Photochemistry and Photobiology A: Chemistry* **2013**, *259*, 59-65 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jphotochem.2013.03.004).
5. Ludwig A. Huber, Peter Mayer, Henry Dube, "Photoisomerization of Mono‐Arylated Indigo and Water‐Induced Acceleration of Thermal *cis*‐to‐*trans* Isomerization," *ChemPhotoChem* **2018**, *2(6)*, 458-464 (https://doi.org/10.1002/cptc.201700228).

Comment: is the fact that electron pairs and alkyl groups are the high-priority groups only because they're just...defined that way? Also, since you can't really use CIP to classify isomers with electron pairs, can you drop a link to a resource specifying the relative priorities of electron pairs and other such groups, if there's any list of that sort?

Comment: if available, please respond.